# Consistency of two statements on the angular momentum operator of a spin-1/2 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, representation-theory, noethers-theorem

It says in the group theory that the angular momentum operator of a spin half particle is just half of the Pauli matrices. However, in the quantum field theory, the angular momentum can be expressed as a functional of the field operators based on the Noether's theorem. Are they consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, (half) the Pauli matrices are a basis for the spin-$1/2$ representation of the $so(3)$ Lie algebra of the angular momentum quantum operators, which in principle correspond to the Noether charges for rotational symmetry.

Comment: Yes $+1$... When one quantize the Dirac field and passes to the one-particle space, the global  spin operator along the $k$-th spatial direction  in the Fock space obtained by the Noether thorem boils down to (a pair) of $\sigma_k/2$.